# How to give EmberJS class a name in console?

Tags: ember.js

I just had this error:

> Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Target <(**subclass of
>   Ember.View**):ember508> does not have action doSubmit

And I was asking myself: **How I can I give my EmberJS subclasses an actual name for its console output?**

**UPDATE**

I'm using require.js:

```
define [
    "ember"
], (Em) ->
    Em.View.extend
        templateName: "user"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like this view is an anonymous view, maybe created by Ember itself if you used {{view Ember.View }} helper.

For defining an named view, you should declare it in js, `App.MyView = Ember.View.extend()`

If this does not answer correctly to your question, I'd suggest to complete it by adding some more code and templates.

**UPDATE**: Seeing https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/system/core_object.js#L251, it seems if you don't define an Ember namespce, this information is lost, but perhaps you can override the toStringExtension function in your view, returning what string you want, and it should work. I've not yet tried this, so I'm interrested :)

Comment: Hm, I see. I updated the question to show how the view is defined. Is there a solution for this - without using the namespace (e.g. adding a custom name field and overwriting toString)?